# BufferedReader ready() method always true

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, bufferedreader

I am trying to test a method in a class which uses a BufferedReader intance:

```
public class ClassTotest {
  private BufferedReader reader;

public boolean methodToTest(){
  while (reader.ready()){
     reader.readLine();
  }
  more code
}
}
```

In my test class I initialized the reader instance using reflection:

```
class MyTest{
 @Test
 public void test(){
   ClassTotest testClass = new ClassTotest();
   Field reader = ClassTotest.class
            .getDeclaredField("reader");
   reader.setAccessible(true);
   StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("testString");
   BufferedReader readerToSet = new BufferedReader(stringReader);
   reader.set(testClass, readerToSet);
   testClass.methodToTest();
 }
```

It goes into the method and I can see that the reader object is initialized, but it always returns true when asked if ready(). So it goes into a infinite loop.

How can I initialize the reader to avoid this infinite loop?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the code in the class that has to be tested.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I initialize the reader to avoid this infinite loop?

You can't.

You have to test the result of the `readLine()` method.  It will return `null` when you get to the end of the stream.

A common idiom is:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // process line
}
```

---

The javadoc for the `ready()` method says:

> "Returns: True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise."

Since a `readLine()` at the end of stream position is guaranteed to return immediately, `ready()` *must* return `true`.

If you consider carefully all of the caveats associated with `ready()` method, it is apparent that it is difficult to use the method in a way that is both correct, performant and useful.  I recommend that you simply avoid it.  If you need to avoid blocking on input, then use either NIO selectors or a NIO channel in non-blocking mode.

---

> Unfortunately, I cannot change the code in the class that has to be tested.

You have identified a BUG in the class under test!  If you can't fix it yourself, then report it to the people who can.  (That's the point of writing unit tests ...)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `ready()` at all? You should be using `readLine()` and stop when it returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `while (reader.ready())` to ,

```
String line = null;
do{
 line = reader.readLine();
}while (line!= null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ready() you can try it as

```
while ((nextLine = in.readLine()) != null)
```